# Windows error message "Inaccessable boot device" after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04, windows-10

I have windows  Pro installed on my PC. But after my brother had installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on the same PC, Windows failed to boot showing an error message saying "INACCESSABLE BOOT DEVICE". taking into consideration that:

- I am a very new to Linux and my brother is useless, so I cannot get any useful information from him about installation process he went through.
- Ubuntu is working fine.
- I can access windows folder and data from Ubuntu (I see only one drive as I guess in other locations)
- I tried to repair or reinstall a fresh windows, but the disk is not recognised by troubeshoot or installation wizard.(even diskpart in command)
- The hard disk is recognised in bios.
- I have tried with secure boot settings in Bios but didnt work.
- I loaded default bios settings, the same result.
- My PC is: Tuf gaming Z490-Plus (Wifi), Intel i3 10105 3.7 GHz, Ram 16GB DDR4, Samsung SSD 970 EVO 250GB
  Please help me getting my windows back. I am even doesnt mind to get rid of Ubuntu.

Comment: "Please help me getting my windows back. I am even doesnt mind to get rid of Ubuntu."  We only support Ubuntu. Installing Windows as the only OS requires zero input from the current OS making this off topic but this reads as hardware issues: if windows does not install either the installer is bad or something in your bios is set to wrong values. I also see this as a problem for your brother ;)

Comment: Hello Rinzwind, I rellay appreciate your response. I believe this question is not off topic as my problem started when Ubuntu is installed. I wish to have both Win10 and Ubintu. Problem is Ubuntu is working fine but it did caused a problem to windows. I seek assistance here because as this is an Ubuntu forum, so I believe many users have faced the same problem. I dont think it is a hardware issue as Ubuntu is working fine but I belive during the Ubuntu installation it made some changes to the disk which can be fixed. Many thanks again.

Comment: "Problem is Ubuntu is working fine" that in itself makes it off topic "but it did caused a problem to windows" No, Ubuntu itself does not interfere with a Windows setup (unless you remove windows during install).  The order is BIOS->GRUB->Windows or Ubuntu.   "INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE" is a windows specific error regarding the boot loader and that needs to be fixed outside of Ubuntu. Maybe https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/ can but you likely need the windows 'repair' option from the windows installer.

Comment: Are both installs UEFI? Can you directly boot Windows from one time boot key, often f12 but varies by vendor, check motherboard manual. Grub only boots working Windows or Windows that is not hibernated. Windows defaults to hibernation with a fast startup setting and often turns that back on with updates.